# Jest: thrown previous Promise rejection when testing Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, jestjs, jest-circus

My Jest tests keep showing `thrown: "I-failed"` when I test promises. Here is the code:

```js
test('testing variable is Promise', () => {
  const rejectPromise = Promise.reject('I-failed')
  expect(rejectPromise instanceof Promise).toBe(true)
})
test('Promis Test', () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 300))
  return promise.then(data => expect(data).toBe(123))
})
```

and the result:

```sh
  ● Promis Test

    thrown: "I-failed"

      at _getError (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:442:18)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

If I change `toBe(123)` to `toBe(1234)`, Jest will show this:

```sh
  ● Promis Test

    thrown: "I-failed"

      at _getError (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:442:18)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)

  ● Promis Test

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1234
    Received: 123
```

It seems that Jest keeps showing an extra error which is not in my code. Apparently the error is caused by the uncaught rejection from the previous test.

Of course I can add a `.catch()` after the `Promise.reject('I-failed')` to handle it, but I think that's not the first goal of my first test:*"`Promise.reject()` is a promise"*.

Is there's a way to keep my first test still detecting *"`Promise.reject()` is a promise"*, and the second test of detect async-promise flow works fine?

Node version: 11.15.0
Jest version: @testing-library/react: ^11.1.0

Comment: Consider reporting a bug with jest-circus

Comment: Works fine for me, can you give a [mre]?

Comment: thanks for comments, the post is updated.

Comment: I have always used the expects to throw syntax.  
  expect(() => {
    const rejectPromise = Promise.reject('I-failed')
  }).toThrowError('I-failed);
 });

Comment: What's the point of testing that a promise is a promise? Just `return expect(rejectPromise).rejects.toBe("I-failed");`, which will also fail with `received value must be a promise or a function returning a promise` if `rejectPromise` isn't a promise. In general leaving unhandled promises lying around is best avoided.

Comment: I'm creating a function that will return the `custom type of value`, which I want `[]` return `array`, `null` returns `"null"`, and `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` both return `promise`

Comment: Just like if we want other programmers pass a `number` to our function, we will check if the params is a `number` before we continue; so do if we want other programmers pass a `Promise` to our function, we will check it before we continue. I know we can use `Promise.resolve()` to make params as a `Promise`, but I want to know if there's an other way to tell want other programmers really pass in.